# Раздача интернета через Wi-Fi от 3G

Tags: wifi, сеть

Здравствуйте.

Я подключаюсь к интернету через 3G модем. Встала задача раздать интернет от компьютера на беспроводную сеть, чтобы подключить ноут или телефон. На роутере USB входов нет, поэтому интернет подключается сначала на компьютере, а потом как-то должно раздаваться. Использую тренднет TEW-651BR.

До этого момента все работало, пока я не переустановил систему. Как я делаю:

Разрешаю общий доступ к интернету через сетевуху (она на компьютере одна). Затем кабель подключаю к сетевухе и к роутеру в порт WAN. Все IP раздаются автоматически что на WAN, что на устройства подключаемые к роутеру по WI-FI.

Раньше работала такая схема, но после переустановки перестало. Брендмауер отключен полностью.

Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1):

В настройках роутера включите DHCP, введите gateway (IP компьютера, к которому подключен модем).

Comment: Как я введу адрес компа, если DHCP включен? Адрес ведь выдается автоматический и каждый раз разный.

Comment: На компьютере поставь статический IP, А для DHCP поставь диапазон раздачи адресов, в который не входит адрес данный ПК

Comment: Мне комп к WAN подключать или к обычному порту в роутере?

Comment: К обычному порту

Answer (score 0):

Луччше использовать роутер с USB, подключаешь к нему 3G модем, настраиваешь и всё, компьютер не нужен!

Comment: нет у меня такого роутера...

Comment: Приобрети за 1500 рублей и будет тебе счастье! :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такую программку как Connectify